# Creating a new SQL Server table from an existing table

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, migrate

I have the job of updating a database table by removing the month column and recreating that table grouping on column fields and summing the hours column.

Here are my instructions: "Create a new PS_StaffHours table without the Month column. Migrate the existing PS_StaffHours data to the new table by grouping on (PSScnID/PSEmpID/Prd/WBSID/RatePrd) and summing the hours."

Now here is the table I scripted out and have to re-create without the Month column and summing the hour column:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PS_StaffHours]
(
    [PSScnID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [PSEmpID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Prd] [int] NOT NULL,
    [WBSID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [RatePrd] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Month] [date] NOT NULL,
    [Hours] [decimal](16, 8) NOT NULL,

   CONSTRAINT [PK_PS_StaffHours] 
       PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([PSScnID] ASC, [PSEmpID] ASC, [Prd] ASC,
                              [WBSID] ASC, [RatePrd] ASC, [Month] ASC)
                   WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
                         IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[PS_StaffHours] WITH CHECK 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_PS_StaffHours_PS_Scenarios] 
        FOREIGN KEY([PSScnID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[PS_Scenarios] ([PSScnID])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[PS_StaffHours] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_PS_StaffHours_PS_Scenarios]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[PS_StaffHours] WITH CHECK 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_PS_StaffHours_PS_Staff] 
        FOREIGN KEY([PSScnID], [PSEmpID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[PS_Staff] ([PSScnID], [PSEmpID])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[PS_StaffHours] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_PS_StaffHours_PS_Staff]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[PS_StaffHours] WITH CHECK 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_PS_StaffHours_PS_WBS] 
        FOREIGN KEY([PSScnID], [WBSID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[PS_WBS] ([PSScnID], [WBSID])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[PS_StaffHours] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_PS_StaffHours_PS_WBS]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[PS_StaffHours] WITH CHECK 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [CK_PS_StaffHours] CHECK ((DATEPART(day, [Month]) = (1)))
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[PS_StaffHours] CHECK CONSTRAINT [CK_PS_StaffHours]
GO

EXEC sys.sp_addextendedproperty 
         @name = N'MS_Description', 
         @value = N'Restricts Month field to the 1st of every month.' , 
         @level0type = N'SCHEMA', @level0name = N'dbo',  
         @level1type = N'TABLE', @level1name = N'PS_StaffHours',  
         @level2type = N'CONSTRAINT', @level2name = N'CK_PS_StaffHours'
GO
```

First, to create the new table I think all I have to do is rename the table name in the CREATE portion of the script and just remove all references of the Month column in the CREATE statement. Am I correct in my thinking about the CREATE script?

Now, here is the script I'm going to use to populate the table without the Month field but I'm not sure if I have the grouping correct because I am getting an error because I'm not `grouping` on the Hours column with the rest. Also, I'm unsure about how to go about `summing` the hours in the query.

My code:

```
SELECT c.PSScnID, c.PSEmpID, c.Prd, c.WBSID, c.RatePrd, c.Hours  
INTO dbo.NewPS_StaffHours 
FROM PS_StaffHours AS c  
GROUP BY c.PSScnID, c.PSEmpID, c.Prd, c.WBSID, c.RatePrd  
GO
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first assumption is correct.
To group by your columns and sum up the hours - try this:

```
SELECT c.PSScnID, c.PSEmpID, c.Prd, c.WBSID, c.RatePrd, SUM(c.Hours) AS Hours
INTO dbo.NewPS_StaffHours 
FROM PS_StaffHours AS c  
GROUP BY c.PSScnID, c.PSEmpID, c.Prd, c.WBSID, c.RatePrd  
GO
```

Sounds like you're going to be creating your table before running your select.
So get rid of the `INTO dbo.NewPS_StaffHours`. Run a create table statement and then and `INSERT INTO newTable VALUES... SELECT`

Comment: need alias, I have added otherwise it will give error